# help to prove statement in number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that for any integer $k$ there is $p$ such that $2^p\leqslant k<2^{p+1}$

The problem starts when I try to use mathematical induction to prove this statement.  In the third part, I found that I cannot prove $k+1<2^{p+1}$.

Comment: this is the statement:Show that for any integer k there is p such that 2^p<k<2^(p+1)

Comment: It is not true for $k=8$

Comment: you need one of the $\lt$ to be $\le$. See my answer

Comment: That is not true for k = 0, there is no real number such that 2^p < 0. Is k supposed to be a *positive* integer?

Comment: yes $k$ is positive integer

Comment: It might help to think of $k$ in base 2.

Answer (score 1):

You need an equality, viz

$$
2^p \le k \lt 2^{p+1}
$$
Proof by induction.

Assume true for $k$. Now for $k+1$, there are two cases

1. $k = \left(2^{p-1}-1\right)$. In this case $2^{p+1} = k+1 < 2^{p+1} + 2^{p+1} = 2^{p+2}$
2. $k < \left(2^{p-1}-1\right)$. In this case $2^p \le k+1 \lt 2^{p+1}$

Comment: thank you very much, but I want to know why you suppose that there are two cases for $k+1$

Comment: The two cases are to see if you need to keep the same p or replace it with (p+1) for the left hand side